# How to add collapsible row details to data.table in R

Tags: r, dt

I would like to do something like the following example here but in R
https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html

Suppose I have the following data:

```
 id         SqlUnixTime        BID        ASK AVG_BID_30D AVG_ASK_30D ASSET_CLASS_RT
1  4 2017-11-27 19:42:45   0.560000   0.600000   0.6259353   0.6926843      CDS_OFFER
2  6 2017-11-27 19:42:44   1.500000   1.650000   1.7260666   1.9176461      CDS_OFFER
3 15 2017-11-27 19:41:21 175.000000 185.000000 187.6814159 187.3303571      CDS_OFFER
4 20 2017-11-27 19:41:06  32.000000  36.000000  33.7221207  38.5045704      CDS_OFFER
5 21 2017-11-27 19:41:06  40.000000  45.000000  42.7813953  47.8341085      CDS_OFFER
6 22 2017-11-27 19:41:06  17.000000  20.000000  16.8596491  21.7543860      CDS_OFFER
```

What I would like is to put the AVG_BID_30D, AVG_ASK_30D, ASSET_CLASS_RT into a collapsible field.

I generate the datatable using something like:

```
DT::datatable( startingTable,
                 extensions = c('FixedColumns', 'Buttons', 'Scroller'),#,# 'FixedHeader'),
                 options = list(
                   dom ='Bfrtip',
                   buttons = c('copy', 'csv', 'excel'),
                   fixedColumns = list(leftColumns = 2, rightColumns = 0),
                   lengthMenu = c(100,200,500,1000),  pageLength = 1000, scrollX = TRUE,
                   deferRender = TRUE,
                   scrollY = scrollPixels,
                   scroller = TRUE

                 ), rownames = FALSE)
```

Here is the raw data from dput in case anyone wants an easy starting set:

```
Browse[1]> dput(temp)
structure(list(id = c(4L, 6L, 15L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 
27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 34L, 64L, 235L, 236L, 237L, 240L, 
250L, 252L, 397L, 398L, 399L, 400L, 401L, 402L, 403L), SqlUnixTime = c("2017-11-27 19:42:45", 
"2017-11-27 19:42:44", "2017-11-27 19:41:21", "2017-11-27 19:41:06", 
"2017-11-27 19:41:06", "2017-11-27 19:41:06", "2017-11-27 19:41:06", 
"2017-11-27 19:41:05", "2017-11-27 19:41:05", "2017-11-27 19:41:05", 
"2017-11-27 19:41:05", "2017-11-27 19:41:05", "2017-11-27 19:41:05", 
"2017-11-27 19:41:05", "2017-11-27 19:41:05", "2017-11-27 19:41:04", 
"2017-11-27 19:40:53", "2017-11-27 19:39:45", "2017-11-27 19:39:45", 
"2017-11-27 19:39:45", "2017-11-27 19:39:45", "2017-11-27 19:39:44", 
"2017-11-27 19:39:44", "2017-11-27 19:39:33", "2017-11-27 19:39:33", 
"2017-11-27 19:39:33", "2017-11-27 19:39:33", "2017-11-27 19:39:33", 
"2017-11-27 19:39:33", "2017-11-27 19:39:33"), BID = c("0.560000", 
"1.500000", "175.000000", "32.000000", "40.000000", "17.000000", 
"16.000000", "34.000000", "19.000000", "20.000000", "18.000000", 
"16.000000", "18.000000", "18.000000", "26.000000", "48.000000", 
"20.000000", "2.250000", "6.500000", "12.500000", "0.560000", 
"1.500000", "-0.750000", "29.000000", "21.000000", "31.000000", 
"23.000000", "23.000000", "24.500000", "27.750000"), ASK = c("0.600000", 
"1.650000", "185.000000", "36.000000", "45.000000", "20.000000", 
"19.000000", "38.000000", "23.000000", "24.000000", "21.000000", 
"19.000000", "21.000000", "21.000000", "29.000000", "52.000000", 
"22.500000", "4.250000", "8.500000", "14.000000", "0.600000", 
"1.650000", "0.750000", "30.000000", "22.000000", "32.000000", 
"24.000000", "23.500000", "25.500000", "28.750000"), AVG_BID_30D = c(0.62593532338311, 
1.72606656184486, 187.681415929204, 33.7221206581353, 42.7813953488372, 
16.859649122807, 16.8352745424293, 38.2131868131868, 19.8462389380531, 
21.6837455830389, 19.2303664921466, 15.9789473684211, 17.6508771929825, 
17.743006993007, 26.8758620689655, 50.4583795782464, 18.3916667719298, 
71.051724137931, 119.892857142857, 178.4875, 0.62593532338311, 
1.72606656184486, 11.5512820512821, 34.0657901642686, 24.562425015, 
36.5573177777778, 25.2553125381945, 25.0763041241458, 26.5439160795207, 
29.7444470416171), AVG_ASK_30D = c(0.692684347826086, 1.91764613778703, 
187.330357142857, 38.5045703839122, 47.8341085271318, 21.7543859649123, 
21.4425956738769, 43.9461538461538, 24.6482300884956, 26.3745583038869, 
23.9319371727749, 20.6157894736842, 22.2649122807018, 22.3601398601399, 
31.6293103448276, 57.4150943396226, 20.9135965964912, 89.8103448275862, 
138.892857142857, 194.615277777778, 0.692684347826086, 1.91764613778703, 
32.2692307692308, 35.6439591540313, 26.2101243930348, 37.9366805546318, 
26.3717278271028, 26.1516929291339, 27.6450218043716, 31.2864096024096
), ASSET_CLASS_RT = c("CDS_OFFER", "CDS_OFFER", "CDS_OFFER", 
"CDS_OFFER", "CDS_OFFER", "CDS_OFFER", "CDS_OFFER", "CDS_OFFER", 
"CDS_OFFER", "CDS_OFFER", "CDS_OFFER", "CDS_OFFER", "CDS_OFFER", 
"CDS_OFFER", "CDS_OFFER", "CDS_OFFER", "CDS_OFFER", "CDS_OFFER", 
"CDS_OFFER", "CDS_OFFER", "CDS_OFFER", "CDS_OFFER", "CDS_OFFER", 
"BOND_OFFER", "BOND_OFFER", "BOND_OFFER", "BOND_OFFER", "BOND_OFFER", 
"BOND_OFFER", "BOND_OFFER")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-30L), .Names = c("id", "SqlUnixTime", "BID", "ASK", "AVG_BID_30D", 
"AVG_ASK_30D", "ASSET_CLASS_RT"))
```

Comment: @Jealie: Respectfully, your comment is incorrect. The very first line on the ?DT::datatable help file specifically states: "This function creates an HTML widget to display rectangular data (a matrix or data frame) using the JavaScript library DataTables." It runs on the same library. I want a table that does the folding as in the linked example.

Comment: @Jealie: Ah -- changed! Thanks.

Comment: Hi, I found a small example which goes in the right direction:
https://rstudio.github.io/DT/002-rowdetails.html

Comment: See here for examples: https://gist.github.com/stla/e3607e3cf87ddbe70b7134d4a1c874d9